# How to update the "Total Items Quantity" count in the checkout sidebar when updating the mini cart from checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-summary, magento2minicart

I am using Magento version 2.3.5. Here, you can see that my minicart contains qty 3 but my checkout cart summary shows the wrong quantity as 2. This is what happens when I update the qty via minicart from the checkout page.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi, can anyone please help on this?